# TensorFlow Android example: Cannot find WORKSPACE file

Tags: ubuntu, tensorflow

I installed TensorFlow on Ubuntu. I also installed Android NDK and SDK, in order to build the example application. According to the [instructions](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/android/README.md), I now need to edit the `WORKSPACE` file to set the NDK and SDK installation paths, but I cannot find the `WORKSPACE` file.

Could you please advise me how I can locate the WORKSPACE file?

Answer (score 1):

The [`WORKSPACE` file](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/WORKSPACE) is in the root directory of the [TensorFlow git repository](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow). It sounds like you may have installed a binary version of TensorFlow—at present you must build the Android example [from source](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/get_started/os_setup.html#installing-from-sources).

Comment: To install tensorflow, first I run:                                                                     $ sudo apt-get install python-pip python-dev                                               $ sudo pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.7.1-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl

Comment: Then to build Tensorflow Android Camera Demo  run:                          clone https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow.git --recurse-submodules    Is there conflict between this two commans?

Comment: No conflict: the `WORKSPACE` file will be in whatever directory you `git clone`d the repository into.

Comment: Because when I want to import MNIST data using:                                   from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/", one_hot=True)            I get this error:  mehsad@mehsad-VirtualBox:~$ mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/", one_hot=True)
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Comment: Ah, you need to input those commands into a Python interpreter. That error is because you're entering the commands directly into the `bash` shell. Try starting `python` first and typing those commands at the `>>>` prompt.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I forgot to run python first. I have downloaded the bazel installer and ran below commands in terminal opened at installer folder to install bazel:                                                                                         $ chmod +x bazel-0.1.5-installer-linux-x86_64.sh

$ ./bazel-0.1.5-installer-linux-x86_64.sh –-user

Comment: but when I run bazel like this:                                                                         $ bazel build //tensorflow/examples/android:tensorflow_demo                      it does not work

Comment: You will probably need to run `~/bin/bazel` rather than `bazel` since you installed with the `--user` flag.

Comment: mehsad@mehsad-VirtualBox:/$ ~/bin/bazel-0.1.5-installer-linux-x86_64.sh –-user
bash: /home/mehsad/bin/bazel-0.1.5-installer-linux-x86_64.sh: No such file or directory

Comment: No, if you've already *installed* `bazel`, then it should be available as `~/bin/bazel`. So you can build the example as `$ ~/bin/bazel build //tensorflow/examples/android:tensorflow_demo`.